# Change height of specific dynamic prototype cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dynamic prototype table view. This table view displays an array of structs. Each struct is being represented by two cells, to be exact by `DateCell` and `timelineCell`.

In this case the date cell is the header and added with: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {`.

I want the `DateCell` (HeaderCell) on the top of the table view (first index of array) to have a different look. I've figured out how to change the background etc. (see `viewForHeaderInSection`) of this header, but **how can I change the height of this exact cell?**

```
extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return addDataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.section]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell") as! TimelineCell

        cell.setDrivenKm(drivenKm: rowData.driven)
        cell.setConsumedL(consumedL: rowData.consumedL)
        cell.setPricePerLiter(pricePerLiter: rowData.pricePerLiter)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let rowData = addDataArray[section]
        guard let last = addDataArray.first else { return nil }
        let color: UIColor!

        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateCell") as! DateCell

        if rowData.date == last.date {
            color = UIColor.white
            headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 22/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            color = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 22/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
        }

        headerCell.setDate(date: rowData.date, color: color)

        return headerCell
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need it dynamic / static header ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan A dynamic header - it displays the date of the user input.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Your answer given previously worked.

Comment: does it works with you or you need a dynamic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement ( for static )

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
   heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}
```

for dynamic

```
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100.0
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and make sure your constraints are hooked propely inside the cell , top , leading , trailing and bottom

Answer (score 0):

Although the previous answer is correct, if you have only two items in the section (the header and the cell) and in your implementation both items are subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, then you can use both of them inside the `cellForRowAt` method. Just increase the number in `numberOfRowsInSection` to 2 and switch over `indexPath.row`.

```
extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return addDataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let rowData = addDataArray[section]
            guard let last = addDataArray.first else { return UITableViewCell() }
            let color: UIColor!

            let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateCell", for: indexPath) as! DateCell

            if rowData.date == last.date {
                color = UIColor.white
                headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 22/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
            } else {
                color = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 22/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
            }

            headerCell.setDate(date: rowData.date, color: color)

            return headerCell
        case 1:
            let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.section]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell", for: indexPath) as! TimelineCell

            cell.setDrivenKm(drivenKm: rowData.driven)
            cell.setConsumedL(consumedL: rowData.consumedL)
            cell.setPricePerLiter(pricePerLiter: rowData.pricePerLiter)

            return cell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

}
```

But if you really want to use a section header, I would use subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for the header.